# Why the script don't work correctly?

Tags: php, frameworks, kohana

I created the add comment script.

Source -

```
if (isset($_GET['do']) and $_GET['do'] == 'comment'){//Ja viss kārtībā, turpinam
                if (!empty($_POST['name']) and !empty($_POST['artcl_id']) and !empty($_POST['homepage']) and !empty($_POST['text'])){
                    $name = trim($_POST['name'],' ');
                    $artcl_id = trim($_POST['artcl_id'],' ');
                    $homepage = trim($_POST['homepage'],' ');
                    $text = trim($_POST['text'],' ');
                    Model::factory('index')
                            ->send_commentar(mysql_real_escape_string($name), mysql_real_escape_string($artcl_id), mysql_escape_string($homepage), mysql_real_escape_string($text), mysql_real_escape_string(time()));
                    ?>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        alert("Thank you! :)");
                    </script>
                    <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=/article/<?php echo $slug; ?>"/>
                    <?php

                } else {
                    $this->template->content = View::factory('index/error')->set('message', 'How to submit empty comment?');
                }
        }
```

But if I am putting white spaces in input field, the script send white spaces. Why the script don't work correctly?

Comment: "they started to work" is an incorrect statement as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're removing whitespaces after you checked on empty fields. Don't you want that turned around? First remove whitespaces and then checking for empty fields?

Comment: at last the answer that nailed it!

Comment: Thank you very much, Zac L, I corrected the script and they is starting work! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here needs to be a lesson on formal logic.
Strictly speaking, you cannot state that "`trim()` doesn't work" based on the indirect observations.

Only direct (and reproduceable!) verification can be a reason for such a statements.

if you happen to check the `trim()` result right after calling it, you can blame this function.
Otherwise you have to *debug your code* to find the actual reason.
Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

trim function will only remove starting and ending whitespaces ... 
if you want to remove white space from whole string then you can use str_replace() function..

```
$artcl_id = str_replace(" ","",$artcl_id);
```

like wise this can be applied to all your fields...

Answer (score -1):

try `trim($var,"\s")` maybe the end char isn't a " " but it's a "\s"